# Doubt in laplace transforms

Tags: laplace-transform

Let $f(t)=e^{t^2}$. Now the laplace transform of $f(t)$ is

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-st}e^{t^2}dt=\int_0^\infty e^{-st+t^2}dt$$

But after this.. How can I proceed? Help me..

Comment: I'm 95% certain you can't take the laplace transform of that function, as it's not bounded by an exponential.

Comment: bounded by exponential means????@Alan

Comment: That there exists a constants C,K such that $f(x)\le Ce^{Kx}$.  WIthout that assumption,  your transform diverges.